# Trying to display text in a block in a plugin page

Tags: php, text

I'm writing a plugin that needs to display text retrieved from another website (text as in lyrics) and the string I get from the query is displayed in a line, while I'd like to display it on multiple lines. When I enter the query address manually in my browser, I get a single line also, but when I display the source code, it's displayed on multiple lines.

Any idea on how I can achieve that? 
Here's my code so that you get an idea of what I mean:

```
public function get_lyrics($artist, $song){
    $url="https://makeitpersonal.co/lyrics?artist=".$artist."&title=".$song;
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data= curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return ($data);
}
```

and where it's called:

```
echo "Lyrics: ".$this->get_lyrics($artist, $song)."</div>";
```

I tried finding a similar question before asking, but as you might have noticed, I had a hard time describing my question precisely enough to make it specific and match any previous question. Sorry if it's been answered before :/

Anyways, thanks for your time! :)

Comment: Example of a song I tried to get the lyrics from: https://makeitpersonal.co/lyrics?artist=Radiohead&title=you

Comment: I've found that displaying it in a textarea makes it a block and not just a line. Not ideal though, any other options?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT 2: I come up with this kind of dirty solution**, which is a function creating temporary array. It will contains the segment of the string you want to add line breaks to. Then we set it back as a string using implode.

```
function breakLines($str,$line_length=30,$implodechar='<br>')
{
    $str_length = strlen($str); 
    $i=0;
    $o=0;
    $tmp = array();//temporary array
    for ($j=0; $j<$str_length; $j++) 
    {
        //if we are at the end of line and
        //that the current char is a space or punctuation char
        if($i>=$line_length && preg_match('/[\s\,\;\.\:]/isu', $str[$j]))
        {
            $i++;                    
            $tmp[]=trim(substr($str,$o,$i));//"\r\n";     
            //we update the offset              
            $o+=$i;
            //we reset our counter
            $i=0;
        }else{                    
            $i++;
        }                
    }

    return implode($implodechar,array_filter($tmp));
}
```

so you can use it simply like :

```
echo "Lyrics: ".breakLines($this->get_lyrics($artist, $song))."</div>";
```

Hope it helps :)

**EDIT: oooops, sorry I understood the contrary of what you are trying to achieve.**

How about using the [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function with a pattern looking for line breaks ?

```
echo "Lyrics: ".preg_replace('/(\R+)?/isu', '',$this->get_lyrics($artist, $song))."</div>";
```

I added the lower "u" modifier for handling encoding.

You can test it here : http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/ns1#preg-replace